# create x86 process under VISTAx64

Tags: winapi, x86, 64-bit, createprocess

I create a x86 process under WindowsServer2003 x64, ok, it work fine!

but I try creating a x86 process under VISTA x64.
it's failed with error code = 216. (ERROR_EXE_MACHINE_TYPE_MISMATCH).

anything difference between 2003x64 and VISTAx64?

Comment: Please post the code creating the process, or atleast just enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: Regarding the running of 32 bit programs there is little difference between these OSs. The 32 bit executable you attempt to run, is it identical on the two different systems.

Answer (score 0):

I was debugging on a client's PC.

There is a 16-bit setup or 16-bit program or some 16-bit code in the product you are using.

This happens when you run a 16-bit EXE from CreateProcess (or CreateProcessEx) in an x64 machine.

Suggestions are

- to contact the vendor of the software, tell them to upgrade their Innosetup to latest version (e.g., 16-bit Innosetup) or InstallShield to latest version (e.g., 16-bit InstallShield) and provide you with a new installer package.
- If the product contains DOS or MS-DOS legacy EXE or COM files, you need to ask the vendor for Win32 or Win64 command-line based version.
- run a copy of Windows Vista (32-bit), Windows 7 (32-bit) inside a VM. Those 16-bit utilities will function as normal.